# How do I get Gimp to save by default in `.xcf.bz2` instead of `.xcf`?

Tags: gimp, file-format

I want to always save my Gimp images as `.xcf.bz2` to save disc space, but I have to change it manually to`.bz2` each type I save.

Is there way to set to change the default save file format to `.xcf.bz2`?

Comment: Looks like a gimp bug, because gimp is saving the last file type that you have used, but doesn't change the default file extension according to that file type, and using extension prior to selected file type.

Comment: So, there is no way to set default. Then I'll send a feature request to gimp developers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you link to the feature request here, so others that come across this question can check on its progress?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Script-Fu to setup default image format. So it's not impossible, but need to search the code or make it yourself. http://www.gimp.org/docs/scheme_plugin/script-fu-gimp.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I write script-fu and as far as I know it's impossible with script-fu to implement this function. you can save file every extension that gimp supports, but you can't override default save dialog.

Comment: This may helps you: http://registry.gimp.org/node/26307

Comment: As I mentioned above, the script saves image as jpg format. I can change it easily to `xcf.bz2`. But the page doesn't show how to change default file format for gimp save dialog.